# Extract and Print only accent characters through regular expression in JAVA

Tags: java, character, extract

Been trying to extract only accent characters[a particular word] from a multiple text files in a folder.
Don't want to remove or convert accent characters to normal characters but print only those characters which are accent in multiple text files and mixed files which has both accent[words] and normal characters. in JAVA

**only to extract all accent specific words.
**
after searching and exploring for a while this a link below is a type of one solution, similar regex but doesn't work as required also select null values and normal characters.
[Regex accented Characters for special field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51732439/regex-accented-characters-for-special-field)

another solution found for that is ([a-zA-Z]|[à-ü]|[À-Ü])
it selects each letter separately not feasible as it not word specific and also selects both normal and accent.

Comment: Please show your code with what you have tried already in a [mre] - Also read the [ask] page for tips on how to improve this questions.  Welcome to [so] - Take the [tour]  (and earn a badge while at it)

Comment: Will definitely work on the way to ask question thanking you for pointing it out would read it clearly and update my question

Comment: Note that sometimes accented characters are represented using the base character plus a "combining diacritic"  so à might be 'a' and U+0300 (combining grave diacritc). You can use `java.text.Normalizer` to deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match word that contains the accent letter you need to go with something like:

```
[a-zA-Zà-üÀ-Ü]*[à-üÀ-Ü][a-zA-Zà-üÀ-Ü]*
```

explenation:

- `[a-zA-Zà-üÀ-Ü]*` - this will match all the accent and not accent letters (so we can have other accent/non-accent letters in our word) - the star `*` modifier is here to match zero or more letters
- `[à-üÀ-Ü]` - this will match exactly one accent letter - to force matching only the words with an accent

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, it cleared the doubt and thanks for the good explanation